# Ryzen CPU Core and Socket Temps - Is this available via sensors?

Tags: cpu, temperature, sensors

Evening!

I'm trying to find a way to display Ryzen CPU Core and Socket temperatures... I'm not sure if there's a way or not.

Here's the output of 'lscpu'

```
server:~$ sudo lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 5 1400 Quad-Core Processor
    CPU family:          23
    Model:               1
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  4
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU max MHz:         3200.0000
    CPU min MHz:         1550.0000
    BogoMIPS:            6387.11
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_
                         tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a m
                         isalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflush
                         opt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vms
                         ave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca sme sev
Virtualisation features:
  Virtualisation:        AMD-V
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                   128 KiB (4 instances)
  L1i:                   256 KiB (4 instances)
  L2:                    2 MiB (4 instances)
  L3:                    8 MiB (2 instances)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Vulnerabilities:
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Mitigation; untrained return thunk; SMT vulnerable
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

This is the output of 'sensors'

```
server:~$ sudo sensors
radeon-pci-0900
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +43.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

it8792-isa-0a60
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in1:           1.09 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in2:           1.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
+3.3V:         1.67 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in4:           1.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in5:           1.11 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in6:           2.78 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)  ALARM
3VSB:          1.66 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
Vbat:          1.54 V
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +30.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +34.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
temp3:        +37.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +60.1°C
```

The temp1/temp2/temp3 are not from the CPU - I think they're from sensors on the motherboard - and they havne't changed

The k10temp 'Tctl' value is the temperature of the CPU...

I'm running a Gigabyte AB350-Gaming 3-CF motherboard.

Is there anyway of getting the individual CPU temps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using vitals gnome-shell extension.(https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/) I can easily read my CPU temp from this also as k10temp Tctl, but not the cores individually. **However** they advertise the reading of individual cores as well (see README on their Github page (https://github.com/corecoding/Vitals).

Therefore I assume if your PC has the necessary sensors it will.
(I run an AMD Ryzen, **but** I have a laptop, so it stands to reason why mine does not have the required sensors.)